# Tic tac toe program keeps skipping over a three-in-a-row

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a Tic-tac-toe program. When checking for a win with "X", it completely skips over the winning line, even though there is a three in a row.

This problem occurred earlier on and then I fixed it with a while loop, but it's back and now I'm unsure what to do.

I thought about trying with a nested `for` loop, but I've only used it for iterating two dimensional arrays.

The problem seems to be in the `gameWinCheck` method:

```
        //creating a two dimensional  array
        GameBoard = new String [3][3]; //allows X's and O's to be placed on the board
        while(counter <=1 && winCheckX == false && winCheckO); {
            GameBoard [0][0] = "X";
            GameBoard [0][1] = "X";
            GameBoard [0][2] = "X";
            GameBoard [1][0] = "4";
            GameBoard [1][1] = "5";
            GameBoard [1][2] = "6";
            GameBoard [2][0] = "7";
            GameBoard [2][1] = "8";
            GameBoard [2][2] = "9";
            printGameBoard();
            mainWindow.println("Its your turn! Please choose a spot on the grid to place your X");
            usersMove = mainWindow.readLine();
            printGameBoard();//called to reprint the grid after a move*/
            gameWinCheck();
        }
        if(winCheckX == true) {
            mainWindow.println("Congrats you've won!");
        }
        else if(winCheckX && winCheckO == false) {
            mainWindow.println("Its a tie! Would you like to try again?");
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.println("The bot won this time, would you like to try again");
        }
    }
    
    public static void printGameBoard() {
        freeSpace = true;

        //personal note: if (GameBoard [0][0] .equals " "){//.equals because its a string
        //}
        mainWindow.println("-------------");
        mainWindow.print("|");
        //square 1
        if(GameBoard[0][0].equals ("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[0][0].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 2
        if(GameBoard[0][1  ].equals ("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[0][1].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 3
        if(GameBoard[0][2].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[0][2].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.println("|"); //closing square 3
        mainWindow.println("-------------");
        mainWindow.print("|");
        //square 4
        if(GameBoard[1][0].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        } 
        else if(GameBoard[1][0].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 5
        if(GameBoard[1][1].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[1][1].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 6
        if(GameBoard[1][2].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[1][2].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.println("|");//closing square 6
        mainWindow.println("-------------");
        mainWindow.print("|");
        //square 7
        if(GameBoard[2][0].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[2][0].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" ");
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 8
        if(GameBoard[2][1].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
        }
        else if(GameBoard[2][1].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
        }
        else {
            freeSpace = true;
            mainWindow.print(" ");
        }
        mainWindow.print(" |");
        //square 9
        if(GameBoard[2][2].equals("X")) {
            mainWindow.print("X");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else if(GameBoard[2][2].equals("O")) {
            mainWindow.print("O");
            freeSpace = false;
        }
        else {
            mainWindow.print(" "); 
            freeSpace = true;
        }
        mainWindow.println("|");//closing square 9
        mainWindow.println("-------------");              
    } 


    public static void gameWinCheck() {
        //checking for 3 in a row for X horizontally
        //winning combinations
        //123 456 789 147 258 369 159 357
        if(GameBoard[0][0] + GameBoard[0][1] + GameBoard[0][2] == "X") {
            winCheckX = true;  
        }
        else if(GameBoard[0][0] + GameBoard[0][1] + GameBoard[0][2] == "O") {
            winCheckO = true;
        }
        else{
            winCheckX = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if all of this was needed.

Comment: **JavaScript != Java**

Comment: Also, can you please format your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code, but to name a few:

- In the `while` loop at the top, the first thing you do is to reset the board to a fixed position... and every iteration will do this. So there can be no progress in the game.
- The `while` condition has this check: `&& winCheckO`, which means the loop should continue when player "O" has won: this is obviously wrong. The loop should **stop** in that case. It seems you think that `winCheckX == false && winCheckO` would assert that both variables are false, but that's not what happens. This expression is short for `winCheckX == false && winCheckO == true` or shorter: `!winCheckX && winCheckO`. Again, this is wrong. You want to check `!winCheckX && !winCheckO`
- The user is prompted for a move *without* first checking whether the game is already over. Obviously when the game is over, the user should not be asked to enter a move.
- `usersMove` is doing nothing to the board. The very next statements prints the board, and a code-comment reads *"called to reprint the grid after a move"*, but the grid didn't change. There is no code that actually performs the move.
- `gameWinCheck` is not making checks correctly. `GameBoard[0][0] + GameBoard[0][1] + GameBoard[0][2] == "X"` is comparing a string of length 3 with a string of length 1, so that is never going to be equal. For the example board (where all these three cells have an "X") the comparison made is `"X" + "X" + "X" == "X"` which comes down to saying `"XXX" == "X"`, which is not true. And secondly, as you've noted in a comment, it is advised to use `equals`. So you'll want to do something like `(GameBoard[0][0] + GameBoard[0][1] + GameBoard[0][2]).equals("XXX")`
- `else { winCheckX = false; }` *could* be OK, but then why is not the same done for `winCheckO`. It is better to initialise these two as `false` at the start of `gameWinCheck` and only have them set to `true` afterwards (when winning lines are detected) -- never again to `false`.
- Related to the above point: in `printGameBoard` you are setting `freeSpace` to `false` and `true` multiple times: it may go from one to the other and back. This is wrong: once it is clear there is a free space, nothing else on the board can determine that `freeSpace` should become `false`. So start by an initialisation of `freeSpace = false` and only have your `if..else` structures setting it to `true` (never to `false`). The idea is that once you have found a free spot, then you know there is a free spot (obviously).
- The `if` condition `winCheckX && winCheckO == false` is showing a similar mistake as the `while` loop condition. It should be `!winCheckX && !winCheckO`.

The code you showed has many variables which are not declared or used. I suppose that is done elsewhere in your code. Given the number of problems in the code you shared, it seems quite likely you have more mistakes in the code you haven't shown.